# Is there a useful $\mathbb{H}^3$ analogue for a "pair of pants"?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

2-dimensional surfaces with negative Euler characteristic have a [pants decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants_(mathematics)) which cuts the surface into pairs of pants. I'm curious if there is an analogue a dimension up.

A pair of pants has three 1-dimensional boundary components. In the Poincaré disk, a pair of pants resembles a triangle defined by three disjoint geodesics, which are those boundary components. Here is an example with a pair of pants highlighted on the Klein Quartic surface.

[image: KQ with a pair of pants highlighted]

In $\mathbb{H}^3$, I'm picturing a volume with four boundary components (geodesic surfaces), something with a tetrahedral look in the Poincaré ball model.

If such a thing is a useful concept and has appeared in the literature, I would appreciate references.

Comment: The trouble with this idea is that for any compact hyperbolic manifold $M$ with totally geodesic boundary, each component of $\partial M$ is a closed surface of negative Euler characteristic whose fundamental group injects into $\pi_1 M$.